# Not able to handle windows authentication window using Appium in safari browser

Tags: windows, macos, authentication, safari, appium

We are automating our website using Appium in Mac iOS device .
when we access our application, it shows windows authentication pop up window. we used the format(https;//username:password@test.com) to handle the windows popup window in chrome and Firefox browser  and it is working fine . but windows authentication popup window is appearing in safari browser. could you please let us know how we can handle windows popup window in safari browser

my system configuration
Mac OS version 10.14.5(macOS Mojave)
Appium version 1.14.2
iPhone version 12.4

Comment: Maybe you should try to dig into if the browser is set up to not accept the insecure basic authentication https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication but only digest or formsbased

Answer (score 0):

What does the windows popup in Safari browser look like? If it's a standard login form with username / password inputs, you may need to locate the username / password textfield elements & call `SendKeys`.

I recommend using the Appium inspector to reproduce your scenario & inspect the Safari browser there.

I have faced a similar issue when handling my organization's single sign on page. After logging in & automatically closing the sign on browser page, my AppiumDriver context became stale & stopped working. so I had to call `Driver.BackgroundApp();` to fix it.

If the username / password input is an 'Alert' style popup, you can refer to this forum here which has a few workarounds:

https://discuss.appium.io/t/handle-http-authentication-on-ios-safari/1480/7

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for replying my question .
the below code is working perfectly

```
driver.get("https://test.com"); 
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("uname"));
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("pwd"));
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("login"));
driver.context("WEB_VIEW");
```